# "No such file or directory" BUT the file actually exist! / Executable problems

Tags: command-line, games

I've been using Ubuntu (13.10) for a couple of months, and I really liked. But it crashed often and that's something that I didn't liked. I was able to run all my files in my terminal without any problem, like my favourite games. And also the executable files. I was able to run them perfectly.

Then elementary Luna OS came out and I decided to give it a try. When I installed was really quick, but after some days I realized that I couldn't open most of my files on the terminal. Just a few, I can't play games anymore because of that problem. Also, I can't open executable files.

So, I decided to reinstall Ubuntu, and guess what? I wasn't able to do nothing! my games and everything, I couldn't open them because the terminal didn't let me. Always displaying the message `"no such file or directory"` while the file actually exist.

Also tried in Linux mint, same thing. I've tried everything, can't do anything. Could some of you help me.

All of my desktops were x64 bits edition. Right now I'm running Linux mint 16 petra cinnamon desktop x64.

How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like they don't have executable permissions. Use `ls -l` and look for the `x` in the permissions description at the start of each line.

If they don't have have executable permissions you can them using `chmod a+x fileName`

Comment: Also try ./filename. The directory where the file you are trying to execute lives may no longer be in your PATH.